How do I integrate my Tkinter code with the rest of my Python code?
In my computer science class, I have to add buttons to a Python program. I used Tkinter to create the buttons. However, the buttons are not doing anything to modify the program.
So here is how the program flow is. I produce the buttons in some sort of remote. After that, I wrote the main function's code which is to do what the user says to do. From there, the user is supposed to press a button to return the results of the engineering calculator, or just to quit.
Code is here:
# Beam Tool is a program which studies properties of rectangular beams and calculates the centroid and inertia of said beam. It is also capable of comparing two beams and their properties.
# You use buttons to control what the program does

from tkinter import *

buttons = Tk()

def button1():
    response = 1

def button2():
    response = 2
    
def button3():
    response = 3

def button4():
    response = 4
    
def button5():
    response = 5
    
button1 = Button(buttons, text="CENTROID CALCULATE", command=button1)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(buttons, text="CENTROID COMPARE", command=button2)
button2.pack()

button3 = Button(buttons, text="INERTIA CALCULATE", command=button3)
button3.pack()

button4 = Button(buttons, text="INERTIA COMPARE", command=button4)
button4.pack()

button5 = Button(buttons, text="QUIT", command=button5)
button5.pack()

def main():
    # beam_data = [base, height, depth, centroid coordinates(base, height, depth) or inertia]  
    beam_data_1 = []
    beam_data_2 = []
    loop_cond = True
    # over here I made a forever loop that breaks when you want to end the code
    response_cycle(beam_data_1, beam_data_2)

def response_cycle(beam_data_1, beam_data_2):
    # this is how the beam tool process goes on and on if people want to do various things
    response = 0
    print("Hello welcome to Beam Tool! What would you like to do today? Press 1 to calculate the centroid of a beam, press 2 to calculate the inertia of a beam, press 3 to calculate and compare centroids of two beams, press 4 to calculate and compare inertias of two beams, press 5 to quit")
    buttons.mainloop()
    if response == 1 or response == 2:
        choice1(response, beam_data_1)
    if response == 3 or response == 4:
        choice2(response, beam_data_1, beam_data_2)
    if response == 5:
        print("Bye Bye ️")
        
        
def choice1(response, beam_data):
    # user input needed for one beam
    beam_data.append(int(input("what is the base of the beam?")))
    beam_data.append(int(input("what is the height of the beam?")))
    beam_data.append(int(input("what is the depth of the beam?")))
    if response == 1:
        print(centroid(beam_data))
        main()
    if response == 2:
        print(inertia(beam_data))
        main()
        
def choice2(response, beam_data_1, beam_data_2):
    # lots of user input for two beams
    beam_data_1.append(int(input("what is the base of the first beam?")))
    beam_data_1.append(int(input("what is the height of the first beam?")))
    beam_data_1.append(int(input("what is the depth of the first beam?")))
    beam_data_2.append(int(input("what is the base of the second beam?")))
    beam_data_2.append(int(input("what is the height of the second beam?")))
    beam_data_2.append(int(input("what is the depth of the second beam?")))
    if response == 3:
        print(centroid(beam_data_1))
        print(centroid(beam_data_2))
        main()
    if response == 4:
        print(inertia(beam_data_1))
        print(inertia(beam_data_2))
        main()


def centroid(beam):
    #how centroid of beams will be calculated
    centroid_coords = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(len(beam)):
        j = beam[i]
        j = j/2
        centroid_coords.append(j)
    beam.append(tuple(centroid_coords))
    return beam 
    
    
def inertia(beam):
    #how inertia of beams will be calculated
    depth=beam[2]
    height=beam[1]
    height2=height*height*height
    inertia=(depth*height2)/12
    beam.append(inertia)
    return beam    
    
main()


Seems like your code works fine? In that case, post your question here.

All of your button functions are completely pointless - they just set a local variable, which immediately vanishes when the function exits.  The normal approach would be to put the action you intend the buttons to trigger directly in those functions.

It is not a good design of calling input() in GUI application.

What you could do, is make "response" a global variable, by declaring it at the top of the code, after import but before the initialisation of tkinter. you could, for example, do:
from tkinter import *
response = 0
buttons = Tk()

Try it, and hopefully it helps!
